# I would like to calculate RMSE and MSE for Prophet , SARIMA and Ensemble models from KATS

Tags: python, time-series, forecasting, kats

I have conducted an analysis where I have forecasted my data frame by converting it into timeseries data. I would like to calculate RMSE and MSE for Prophet, SARIMA and Ensemble models from KATS.

**For SARIMA**
Code:

```
from kats.models.sarima import SARIMAModel, SARIMAParams
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore')
# create SARIMA param class
params = SARIMAParams(p=2 , 
    d=1, 
    q=1, 
    trend = 'ct', 
    seasonal_order=(1,0,1,12)
    )
# initiate SARIMA model
m = SARIMAModel(data=ts, params=params)
# fit SARIMA model
m.fit()

# generate forecast values
fcst = m.predict(
    steps=HOURS ,
    include_history = True
    )

# make plot to visualize
plt1 = m.plot()
plt.xlabel('Time (in days)')
plt.ylabel('Noise Level (db)')
```

Forecasted result:
[SARIMA Forecasting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57MUV.png)

**For Prophet**

Code:

```
from kats.models.prophet import ProphetModel, ProphetParams

# create a model param instance
params = ProphetParams(seasonality_mode='multiplicative') # additive mode gives worse results

# create a prophet model instance
m = ProphetModel(ts, params)

# fit model simply by calling m.fit()
m.fit()

# make prediction for next HOURS hours
fcst = m.predict(steps=HOURS, include_history = True)

# plot to visualize
plt2 = m.plot()
plt.xlabel('Time (in days)')
plt.ylabel('Noise Level (db)')
```

Forecasted result:

[Prophet Forecasting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdTe5.png)

Can anyone please tell me how can I achieve it? I have tried several summary statistic techniques but it doesn't seem to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [Kats 201 tutorial notebook](https://github.com/facebookresearch/Kats/blob/main/tutorials/kats_201_forecasting.ipynb) has examples in sections 4 and 5 showing how to use Kats to compute an `evaluation_function` (here, MAE) and to perform backtesting to compute many error metrics (MAPE, SMAPE, MAE, MASE, MSE, RMSE).

Comment: Thank you for the response. I was able to find this but the problem is occurring with the Ensemble model. Backtesting runs fine for SARIMA and Prophet Models but it shows Attribute error during Ensemble. Could you please help me with that?